# Bootstrap: Why is my slider banner not lining up with the rest of the page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider

I can't seem to figure out what is constraining my banner to 1170px rather than 1200px? As you can see from the live preview, the left side of the banner does not extend out to the edge of the page. Anyone have any clues? Thanks!

Live [preview here](http://www.ogmda.com/test/index2.html).

Comment: check headerrow class in your css

Comment: I did...didn't see anything suspicious. The page is fine, just that my slider does not seem to extend left like the other parts of that page.

Comment: @media (min-width: 1200px)  
.row {
margin-left: -30px;
}  check this out

Answer (score 0):

Your `.row` class has `margin-left` set to `-30px`. Try setting it to `0px`. In the future try to avoid setting margins below zero; it works but it doesn't look nice and in most cases may be done otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I simply contained the banner with a .row class (comes default with Bootstrap) and that fixed the issue. I discovered this from looking at one of the Bootstrap default templates from the Bootstrap website and they simply wrapped the banner with a .row class. I forgot to add that to my banner...so that fixed it. In conclusion, to set up the 12 column grid you need to first establish the grid itself (hence, the default .row class).